# Why Oracle Linux cannot recognize php packages?

Tags: php, bash

I checked [here](https://superuser.com/a/28635/440652) that using `php -v` or `php -i` should show my php version. Although, when I type these commands, I got `-bash: php: command not found`. When I type `rpm -qa | grep php` I get

```
php71w-bcmath-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64
php71w-pdo-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64
php71w-ldap-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64
mod_php71w-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64
php71w-mbstring-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64
php71w-xml-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64
php71w-mysql-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64
php71w-gd-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64
php71w-common-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64
```

And when I type `yum provides php | grep php71w` (showing all packages that has `php` command and has `php71w` on its name) I get

```
mod_php71w-7.1.8-2.w7.x86_64 : PHP module for the Apache HTTP Server
mod_php71w-7.1.9-1.w7.x86_64 : PHP module for the Apache HTTP Server
mod_php71w-7.1.9-2.w7.x86_64 : PHP module for the Apache HTTP Server
mod_php71w-7.1.10-1.w7.x86_64 : PHP module for the Apache HTTP Server
mod_php71w-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64 : PHP module for the Apache HTTP Server
mod_php71w-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64 : PHP module for the Apache HTTP Server
```

What I'm missing? If `mod_php71w-7.1.11-1.w7.x86_64 : PHP module for the Apache HTTP Server` has php command and it's listed as installed, why `php -v` is not recognized?

Comment: You need the php-cli package as well.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Could you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP Command Line Interface is typically not installed by default. Just find the correct php-cli package for your distro/version and install it.